# R loop regression special

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Sample

```
  OUTCOME=0:9
  X1=1:10
  X2=5:14
  Z1=9:18
  Z2=21:30
  Z3=41:50
  Z4=52:61
  Z5=20:29
  DATA=data.frame(OUTCOME,X1,X2,Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5)
  ADJUSTMENTS=c("X1","X2")
  Z=c(Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5)
  for (i in Z){
 coef(lm(OUTCOME~ADJUSTMENTS + Z));
    lm(OUTCOME~ADJUSTMENTS + Z)$r.squared;
  }
```

I have data and I hope to do this: the DV does not change and the COVS all include X1 BUT I want to loop for VARS Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5,Z6,Z7,Z8 and so forth. Then I aim to store this coefficient for just the Z var such that I have new data frame:

```
Z COEF    RSQUA
Z1 VALUE  VALUE
Z2 VALUE  VALUE
Z3 VALUE  VALUE
Z4 VALUE  VALUE
Z5 VALUE  VALUE
Z6 VALUE  VALUE
Z7 VALUE  VALUE
Z8 VALUE  VALUE
```

Comment: Some data would be helpful for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: @nsinghs thank you for your good advice i have since done so.

Comment: In `OUTCOME~ADJUSTMENTS` the `ADJUSTMENTS` is just a vector of length 2.  It should be only a single vector of the same length as `OUTCOME`